# Pass data from first operator in a pipe into two custom operators?

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3, rxjs

I recently took over an Angular codebase with no access to the previous dev and am struggling to understand some of the RxJS used.

There is currently a 2 step file upload process that I would like to basically replicate for the upload of streamable video. The upload process makes a request to the API receiving form data for uploading files (and now videos). The current code combines the initial file upload request with the form data for every file in a `mergeMap` and makes the requests to S3. This works great for the files but I can't seem to make the same happen for videos.

As far as I understand, I need to create a way to pass data from a `map` operator to two custom operators instead of one. I have tried to use a `forkJoin` inside a `mergeMap` to combine the processes but I kept running into problems with passing data from the initial `map` operator into both functions. Here is my code with the initial upload requests and the custom operator.

```
  addItem(courseCode: string, unitId: string, formValue: AddItemFormValue) {
    return this.courseApi.addItem(courseCode, unitId, body).pipe(
      map(data => data.data),
      this.makeFileUploadRequests(formValue),
      // Trying to add: this.makeVideoUploadRequests(formValue)
    );
  }

  private makeFileUploadRequests<T extends { files: { name: string; params: ServerModel.FileResponse }[] }>(formValue: {
    files: UploadingFile[];
  }) {
    return mergeMap<T, Observable<ServerModel.FileUploadedResponse[] | T>>(data => {
      return Array.isArray(data.files) && data.files.length > 0 ? this.uploadFiles(data.files, formValue.files) : of(data);
    });
  }
```

I think part of what makes this confusing is the syntax used for the custom operators. I have created a similar operator for uploading videos but how do I run both of them while making sure the stream coming from the `map` is passed onto both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is so disappointingly often the case, the answer is, "It depends." Right now, `addItem` is returning an Observable. An Observable is basically a pipe that you can plug into that sometimes emits values. How should values be emitted from the `addItem`'s Observable?

**The General Answer**

The general question you're asking is, "How do I pass an Observable's value through to 2 different operators?" And the general answer is: You create 2 pipes.

For example:

```
// Emits a number every second, which is multiplied by 10
const foo$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  map(v => v * 10)
)

const stringified$ = foo$.pipe(
  map(v => v.toString())
)

const percentage$ = foo$.pipe(
  map(v => v / 100)
)
```

The `pipe` function simply returns another Observable, so that Observable can be fed into another pipe. In your example, that means you could do this:

```
addItem(courseCode: string, unitId: string, formValue: AddItemFormValue) {
  const data$ = this.courseApi.addItem(courseCode, unitId, body).pipe(
    map(data => data.data)
  )

  const fileUpload$ = data$.pipe(this.makeFileUploadRequests(formValue))
  const videoUpload$ = data$.pipe(this.makeVideoUploadRequests(formValue))

  return // We're getting to this...
}
```

**The Conditional Part**

The function `addItem` currently returns an Observable that emits some values, and to keep that consistent we need to return a single Observable that emits some values as well. So now we get to the part where it depends, and what it depends on is this: What values should the Observable returned by `addItem` emit?

There are quite a few options, but here are some of the ones you might consider:

**Option 1:** The `data$` observable should pass info to *both* `makeFileUploadRequests` *and* `makeVideoUploadRequests` no matter what, and the resulting Observable should emit all values emitted by either operator.

In this case, you're going to want to return a new Observable using the `mergeWith` function:

```
return mergeWith(fileUpload$, videoUpload$)
```

**Option 2:** The `data$` observable should pass info to *either* `makeFileUploadRequests` *or* `makeVideoUploadRequests` based on some filter, and the resulting Observable should emit only values emitted by whichever one of the two was used.

This is probably the simplest, because it's a straight-up ternary:

```
return unitId === someConditionOrWhatever ? fileUpload$ : videoUpload$
```

**Option 3:** The `data$` observable should pass info to *both* `makeFileUploadRequests` *and* `makeVideoUploadRequests` no matter what, and the resulting Observable should emit only after *both* of the other Observables have *completed*.

You're going to want to use `forkJoin`, which emits when all of the Observables passed to it have completed:

```
return forkJoin(fileUpload$, videoUpload$)
```

**Option 4:** The `data$` observable should pass info to *both* `makeFileUploadRequests` *and* `makeVideoUploadRequests` no matter what, and the resulting Observable should emit only after *both* of the other Observables have *emitted at least once*.

Your best friend here is `combineLatest`:

```
return combineLatest([fileUpload$, videoUpload$])
```

There are a couple dozen operators in RxJS dedicated to merging 2+ Observables depending on how you want to do it and what the result should be, but hopefully that gives you a good idea.

**TL;DR:** You don't feed it into 2 different operators in a single pipe, you end that pipe and create 2 new ones that plug into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to use the forkjJoin as it seemed like a good fit but the issue was addItem() was being called twice, creating two instances of my object on the database. Instead I used option 2 and made the videoUpload function also upload files.